# How to get text from two elements, convert them to a number and add them in cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, cypress

I'm moving tests from protractor to cypress.

I have two elements like below. I want to get the number and add them and store them in a variable.

```
<span id="num-2">20</span>
```

In protractor I wrote it like below

```
var totalCount =
      parseInt(element(by.id('num-1')).getText()) +
      parseInt(element(by.id('num-2')).getText());
```

I can't figure out how to do it in Cypress.

Comment: Are you planning to assert/expect the two values equal some specific value? It's actually anywhere near as straightforward to save values to a variable within a single test.

Comment: yes, I need to assert the total count with another value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve [aliases/variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Variables) and [get](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get). The trick is that get, invoke, or similar are effectively async and you can't really effectively `await` cypress operations. Instead you can get the first number, parse it, get the second number, parse it, add the numbers and assert/expect:

```
const expectedTotal = 42;

// get element with id #num-1
cy.get('#num-1').then(($num1) => {
  // parse text to int/number
  const num1 = parseInt($num1.text());

  // get element id #num2
  cy.get('#num-2').then(($num2) => {
    // parse text to int/number
    const num2 = parseInt($num2.text());
    
    // expect/assert number total equal to some expected total
    expect(num1 + num2).toEqual(expectedTotal);
  });
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting "Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'Chainable<number>'" error

Comment: @autotest can you update your question with exactly what you have in your code now?

Comment: I was able to confirm this works on an html page with spans with these ids

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my fault. It works. Thank you!